# Custom menu output

Tags: menus

If the menu is with Pages then how can I display the menu item links like this:

http://example.com/#/page/id

I want to use the menu with Angular routes.

I believe this can be done with a custom Walker.

Comment: What do u mean by `If the menu is with Pages ` ? Also, instead of providing a link to a page with no menus, u'd better provide an image of desired output

Comment: The menu is with Pages, meaning that it has only Pages in it (no custom links, no categories etc). I just want the link as a desired output, no styling.

Comment: I would suggest e.g. the  `nav_menu_link_attributes` filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following to modify the links of the menu items that are *pages*:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', function( $atts, $item, $args, $depth )
{
    if( 
          isset( $item->object ) 
       && 'page' === $item->object 
       && isset( $args->theme_location ) 
       && 'primary' === $args->theme_location 
    )
        $atts['href'] = home_url( 
            sprintf( '/#/page/%d',  $item->object_id ) 
        );

    return $atts;
}, 10, 4 );
```

where we target the *primary* theme location.

This should give this kind of links:

```
http://example.tld/#/page/12345
```

Comment: you're welcome, glad it worked for you @KlevisMiho